# SSH connection asks passwrod in putty but not in other client

Tags: ssh, putty, mobaxterm

My admin gave me an ssh connection in [Moba Xterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) application for a remote server with Debian Linux. When I check the configuration of this connection I can see only the remote server name and the SSH port as you can see in the next image.

[image]

When I connect to this server I provide username and no password is requested.

I tried to replicate this connection in putty ssh client. I create a new connection with the some server name and port but when I connect after user name a password is asked. I was wondering did my admin set up the connection with an extra configuration that I did not find? And if so, how can I find it and connect password-less through putty?

Thanks for any answer

Comment: ask your admin.

Comment: @Ipor Sircer I would, but unfortunately he died in a horrific car accident last week, so I guess I am stuck

Comment: Show us Moba Xterm and PuTTY log files for comparison.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl Where can I find those? Putty does generate log files except console output which I think is not helpful at all

Comment: Right-click PuTTY window title, and select "Event log".

Comment: Do both clients (MobaXterm, PuTTY) connect to the server from the same IP?

Comment: yes they use the same ip